# Following Django ForeignKey relationships backwards

Tags: python, django, django-models, relational-database

I have a Django website where I would like to display two graphs (Charta and
Chartb) for a list of stocks, but I'm struggling to define my models.  Right
now, I have multiple related tables in my models.py:

```
from django.db import models

class Stock(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    company = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __unicode__(self):
      return self.name

class Charta(models.Model):
    stock = models.ForeignKey(Stock)
    x_axis = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    y_axis = models.IntegerField(default=0)

class Chartb(models.Model):
    stock = models.ForeignKey(Stock)
    x_axis = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    y_axis = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

My goal is to have a stocks page which lists all stocks in my Stocks table, and
then a details page for each stock where I can show the x and y coordinates for
each chart.  (Once I have these coordinates, I can graph them, but right now I'm
struggling just printing the coordinates on the screen). So far, my views.py
file looks like this:

```
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404
from stocks.models import Stock, Charta, Chartb

def index(request):
    stock_list = Stock.objects.all()
    context = {'stock_list': stock_list}
    return render(request, 'stocks/index.html', context)

def detail(request, stock_id):
    stock = get_object_or_404(Stock, pk=stock_id)
    return render(request, 'stocks/detail.html', {'stock': stock})
```

Doing things this way, I am able to easily get a stocks page showing all stocks
in my table, linking each one to a details page, using the following index.html
file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
    <h1>Stocks</h1>

    {% if stock_list %}
        <ul>
        {% for stock in stock_list %}
            <li><a href="/stocks/{{ stock.id }}/">{{ stock.name }}</a></li>
        {% endfor %}
        </ul>
    {% else %}
        <p>No stocks are available.</p>
    {% endif %}

    </body>
</html>
```

The issue I'm having is displaying the coordinates for each stock in the details
page. I would like to have a details.html page like the following:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
    <h1>Stock Details</h1>

    <!-- This works fine -->
    <p>The name of this stock is <strong>{{ stock.name }}</strong> </p> <br>
    <p>This stock comes from <strong>{{ stock.company }}</strong> </p> <br>

    <!-- This doesn't work -->
    <p>The x values for this stock are: </p>
        <ul>
        {% for x_val in stock.charta.x_axis %}
            <li>x_val</li>
        {% endfor %}
        </ul>
    <p>The y values for this stock are: </p>
        <ul>
        {% for y_val in stock.charta.y_axis %}
            <li>y_val</li>
        {% endfor %}
        </ul>

    </body>
</html>
```

However, I am not able to call the x_values and y_values with something like
`stock.charta.x_axis`.  Is there a better way that I could set up my models so
that I can access the chart data for each stock inside of the details page?
Intuitively, it makes sense to me to have a table listing stocks, and then to
access data for each chart using some kind of SQL join.

I've put a minimal example of this project on github [here](https://github.com/sanp/django_test).

Thanks!

Comment: Did you mean that `x_value` is `x_axis` ? `y_value` respectively.

Comment: @pythonishvili: Ah, yes.  Thanks -- that was a typo.  I've edited the question -- the code still doesn't work with those changes, though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Charta` and `Chartb` have a `ForeingKey` field of `Stock` so you are dealing with a `one-to-many` relationship, when `Stock` is the one side.

In your code you have:

```
{% for x_val in stock.charta.x_value %}
    <li>x_val</li>
{% endfor %}
```

but that's wrong. If you want access to `Charta` objects from a `Stock` object you have to write:

```
{% for charta in stock.charta_set.all %}
    <li> {{ charta.x_axis }} </li>
{% endfor %}
```

note the **charta_set** change. That's becouse Django generates by default and `object manager` called `charta_set` or `chartb_set` for the relationship.

You can modify the model, in order to specify the "relation name" for `charta` and `charb` objects inside a `stock`.

```
class Charta(Model):
    ...
    stock = models.ForeignKey(Stock, related_name='charta')
    ...
```

And change the template code to:

```
{% for charta in stock.charta.all %}
    <li>{{ charta.x_axis }}</li>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thanks -- this is exactly what I was looking for! I remember reading about the <<model>>_set property in the tutorials but I guess I never fully grasped it.

Answer (score 1):

It is very hard to debug in templates because errors are suppressed!! It is much easier to debug in your view

```
def detail(request, stock_id):
    stock = get_object_or_404(Stock, pk=stock_id)
    import pdb; pdb.set_trace();
    return render(request, 'stocks/detail.html', {'stock': stock})
```

The above allows will pause your program at the import pdb statement, and allow you to inspect your stock object.

By default in django, [reverse](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#related-objects) foreignkey is navigated through `<<model>>_set` property

`stock.charta_set` which will return the manager NOT the actual chart instances.  To do that should be

`stock.charta_set.all()`

or in your template:

`stock.charta_set.all`